# Make my view as pretty as NSAlertView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uikit

I have a modal view in my iPhone app (Xcode, Objective C++). How do I make it look as pretty as the system UIAlertView? Specifically, I want:

- rounded-rect window with a border around it
- semitransparent background
- subtle highlight near the top

The transparency can be probably achieved with a less than one alpha channel on the background color. What about the frame and the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iPhone OS 3.0 and later, you can get the rounded corners easily by setting the borderRadius property of the view's layer.

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

You will need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to get the headers for the CALayer class.

You are right about the transparency, just use a color with an alpha component, and make sure that the view is not marked as opaque.

As for a highlight, you could either do it programmatically or using an image.

If doing it programmatically, you will have to use Core Graphics and do some drawing with `CGGradient`.

If using an image, take a look at UIImage's `stretchableImageWithTopCapHeight:leftCapWidth:`; you can resize an image without distorting the corners.

Comment: Surely you meant `cornerRadius` - there's no such thing as `borderRadius` on `CALayer`.

Comment: Oops, fixed! I must have been thinking of the CSS property.